# Typoscript Condition not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, php, css, typo3, typoscript

I want to hide typo3 felogin permalogin option in IE 11 only. For that I've added this code;

```
[browser = msie] && [version >= 11]

plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.showPermaLogin = 0

[global]
```

But this is not working anymore. I am using Typo3 version 4.7.17.

Also how to add a css hack for IE11 ?

Is there anyway to identify IE11 navigator useragent?

Does anybody knows the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your condition has an error. According to the [manual](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-version) the condition should look like shown below:

```
[browser = msie] && [version = >10]

plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.showPermaLogin = 0

[global]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix the problem with:

```
[useragent = *Trident/7.0; rv:11*]
```

Comment: hello and welcome [so]. explain why this works by [edit]ing the answer.

Comment: MS has changed the User Agent string for IE 11. There is no "MSIE" token anymore. This is explained here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625)